# Timeseries Prediction - Python

Tags: python, time, time-series, missing-data, imputation

I have a data for 8 hours where data is not present in between. For example:
[Missing Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LNRb.png)

Can we use any of the timeseries forecasting techniques to predict the missing data in between ? If yes, how ?
As much as I understand we need to historical data to predict or forecast but not aware of the forecasting techniques to predict the missing data in between.
**Note: I am aware of the bfill,ffill and interpolate method.**

Comment: other methods: sequence prediction using dense network, sequence prediction using LSTM